# How to remove element.style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, inline

I have a html code like this

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <aside id="left-sidebar-nav">
            <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed leftside-navigation">
```

and after run, a element.style added to my code...

```
<div id="main">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <aside id="left-sidebar-nav">
                <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed leftside-navigation ps-container ps-active-y" style="left: 0px; height: 776px;">
```

I want to remove `style="left: 0px; height: 776px;"` (or remove just   left: 0px)
or find source of this inline style

so how can i remove or find source.

Comment: may be any plugin/theme...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Using jQuery library:


$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#slide-out").removeAttr("style");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code coming from script you can use important to override that code,

```
.side-nav.fixed.leftside-navigation {
left:auto!important;
}
```

note: you can use parent class name before the class name

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you could squarely remove the style attribute like this:

```
$("#slide-out").removeAttr("style");
```